# How to start Android with React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-studio, react-native

I'm currently on `Starting the Android Virtual Device` on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

But I don't see any AVDs available on AVD Manager. Tried create AVD, but Okay or Create button is greyed out and also cannot scroll down.

After closing, I cannot locate the AVD Manager again. Where can I open it and how can I be able to run `android avd` in a terminal, and select AVD, and `Start...`?

Thank you and will be sure to upvote and accept answer

Comment: Probably it is better if you install Android Studio, then it is easy to handle https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: @appsthatmatter I did but don't I still have to follow through the terminal commands as well?

Comment: for react-native commands yes, but to start your AVD you can do this via the Android Studio IDE